# How to use windows.h in C to create a pop up warning message

Tags: c, popupwindow

I am currently dealing a school project where it required to make a pop up warning message in the C program. However, I have no idea on that. Could somebody giving me some guides?

Comment: Read the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#displaying-a-message-box

Answer (score 2):

MessageBox WinApi function does this trick.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox